# how to change my hostname in erlang

Tags: linux, erlang, rpc, hostname

this is my kvs.erl :

```
-module(kvs).
-export([start/0, store/2, lookup/1]).

start() -> register(kvs, spawn(fun() -> loop() end)).

store(Key, Value) -> rpc({store, Key, Value}).

lookup(Key) -> rpc({lookup, Key}).

rpc(Q) ->
    kvs ! {self(), Q},
    receive
    {kvs, Reply} ->
        Reply
    end.

loop() ->
    receive
    {From, {store, Key, Value}} ->
        put(Key, {ok, Value}),
        From ! {kvs, true},
        loop();
    {From, {lookup, Key}} ->
        From ! {kvs, get(Key)},
        loop()
    end.
```

when i startup erlang using :erl -name zhao -setcookie  abc

and then :  rpc:call(fifar@huihua.sohu-inc.com,kvs,store,[weather,cold]).

it show error:

```
(zhao@zjm1126.sohu-inc.com)1> rpc:call(fifar@huihua.sohu-inc.com,kvs,store,[weather,cold]).         
** exception error: bad argument in an arithmetic expression
     in operator  -/2
        called as 'fifar@huihua.sohu' - 'inc.com'
```

i think it is about linux hostname ,

but i use this linux shell : hostname -a

it cant show "huihua.sohu-inc.com"

so what can i do ,

thanks

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the  error description you have an error on the binary operator "-". you would only require to change the

```
(zhao@zjm1126.sohu-inc.com)1> rpc:call(fifar@huihua.sohu-inc.com,kvs,store,[weather,cold]).
```

to

```
(zhao@zjm1126.sohu-inc.com)1> rpc:call('fifar@huihua.sohu-inc.com',kvs,store,[weather,cold]).
```

And you will get your code running. Erlang console is seeing **fifar@huihua.sohu** and **inc.com** as two distinct atoms and seeing *fifar@huihua.sohu-inc.com* as a **difference operation between two atoms**. I advice you to follow this quote from erlang [reference manual](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html):

> An atom is a literal, a constant with name. An atom should be enclosed in single quotes (') if it does not begin with a lower-case letter or if it contains other characters than alphanumeric characters, underscore (_), or @.